# Ruby Watir - how to select <a onclick="new Ajax.Request

Tags: ruby, ajax, watir

Hi I'm trying to select an edit button and I am having difficulty selecting it.

```
<td>
  <a onclick="new Ajax.Request('/media/remote/edit_source/3', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true}); return false;" href="#">
  <img title="Edit" src="/media/images/edit.gif?1258500617" alt="Edit">
</a>
```

I have the number at the end of ('/media/remote/edit_source/3') the which changes and I have stored it in @rep_id variable.

I can't use xpath because the table changes often. Any suggestions? Any help is greatly appreciated. Below is what I have tried and fails. I am fairly new to watir and love it, but occasionally I run into things like this and get stumped.

```
browser.a(:text, "/media/remote/edit_source/#{@rep_id}").when_present.click
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
browser.a(:text, "/media/remote/edit_source/#{@rep_id}").when_present.click
```

fails because:

1. The content you are looking for is in the onclick attribute (rather than the text)
2. The locator is passed a string for the second parameter. This means that it is looking for something that exactly matches that. Given that you are only using part of the text/attribute, you need to use a regexp.

If you are using watir-webdriver, there is support for locating an element by its :onclick attribute. You can use a regexp to partially match the :onclick attribute.

```
browser.link(:onclick => /#{Regexp.escape("/media/remote/edit_source/#{@rep_id}")}/).when_present.click
```

If you are also using watir-classic (for IE testing), the above will not work. Instead, you can check the html of the link. Checking the html also works in watir-webdriver, but could be less robust than using :onclick.

```
browser.link(:html => /#{Regexp.escape("/media/remote/edit_source/#{@rep_id}")}/).when_present.click
```

Answer (score 1):

From your example, it looks like you are using the URL from the onclick event handler as a `:text` locator, which I'd expect to fail unless that text does exist.

You could potentially click on the `img`.  Examples:

```
browser.image(:title, "Edit").click 
browser.image(:src, "/media/images/edit.gif?1258500617").click 
browser.image(:src, /edit\.gif\?\d{10}/).click                  # regex the src
```

Otherwise, you might need to use the `fire_event` method to trigger the event handler, which looks like this:

```
browser.link(:id, "foo").fire_event "onclick"
```

These are the links to the `fire_event` docs for [watir](http://rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-classic/Watir/Element#fire_event-instance_method) and [watir-webdriver](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#fire_event-instance_method) for reference.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The regular expression worked perfectly. Thank you so much. I was really stuck.